# "Mitleid" vs. "Mitgefühl"

Tags: meaning

Könnt Ihr mit bitte helfen, Folgendes zu verstehen: Hat das Wort *Mitleid* eine positive oder negative Konnotation im Deutschen? (ich habe hier [Translating emotional sensitivity words](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/translating-emotional-sensitivity-words) nachgelesen, bin aber leider nicht schlauer geworden). Im Unterricht ist die Frage, ob wir behinderten Menschen aus Mitleid oder aus Mitgefühl helfen, unbeantwortet geblieben...

Comment: Meinst Du denn, dass alle Teilnehmer Eures Unterrichts das Gleiche empfinden? Kommt außer Mitleid o. Mitgefühl nicht auch anderes in Betracht, etwa eine emotionslose Hilfsbereitschaft oder der Wunsch gegenüber dritten als Hilfsbereit zu gelten? Mitleid und Mitgefühl sind Gefühle - wieso soll man die überhaupt bewerten? Schließlich stellt sich die Frage nach Mitleid mit jemandem, der gar nicht leidet, dem man das nur unterstellt, weil man sich gescheut hat, hinzuschauen. Ist es nicht arg einfältig für all die Möglichkeiten ein vorgefasstes Werturteil bereit zu haben?

Comment: Man könnte den betroffenen Menschen ja auch aus einem moralisch-intellektuell begründeten Anstandsbewusstsein helfen, ohne sich dabei emotional einzubringen.

Comment: Die Frage ist auch, was Du mit Konnotation meinst. Welche Nebenbedeutung soll Mitleid denn haben? Bevor man diese bewertet, wenn man das überhaupt anstrebt, muss man sie doch erst inhaltlich bestimmen. Siehe auch die von mir angestoßene Metadiskussion hier: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1162/266

Answer (score 3):

Die beiden Wörter haben eine ähnliche Bedeutung. Manche sehen im Mitleid eher ein gemeinsames Leiden (auch des an sich Unbeteiligten), während Mitgefühl eher dafür verwendet wird, dass einem das Leid des anderen bewusst ist und mehr für den Wunsch steht, dem anderen zu helfen. Ich weiß aber nicht, in wieweit diese Unterscheidung von Allen so gesehen wird.

Unabhängig davon hat das Wort und die Eigenschaft normalerweise eine positive Bedeutung. Dass heißt aber nicht, dass derjenige, dem das Mitleid entgegen gebracht wird, dieses auch haben möchte, insbesondere wenn es in die Richtung des englischen "pity" geht, jemanden bedauern. Das kann verschiedene Gründe haben, möglicherweise möchte derjenige einfach nicht den Fokus darauf lenken oder es ist etwas, was man sowieso nicht ändern kann, oder derjenige möchte nicht eine Schwäche als sein unterscheidendes Merkmal in den Augen der anderen sehen.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen die negative Konnotation von _Selbstmitleid_.

Comment: RalfFriedl: vielen Dank für die Antwort! Genau das ist mein Problem: in meiner Muttersprache gibt es zwei Begriffe dafür, die den englischen „pity“ und „compassion“ entsprechen würden, daher weiß ich manchmal nicht, ob man mit einer Person mitfühlt oder ob sie einem leid tut

Answer (score 2):

In meinem Sprachgebrauch ist Mitleid ein Teil des Mitgefühls. Mitleid bezieht sich dabei nur auf das Leiden meines Gegenübers, wohingegen Mitgefühl auch andere Emotionen umfasst, die ich an meinem Gegenüber sehe. Als Beispiele würden mir hier Wut oder auch Enttäuschung einfallen.

Mitleid geht eher in die Richtung "den anderen bedauern". Mitgefühl dagegen assoziire ich mit Hilfsbereitschaft.

Ich denke einen Unterschied macht auch, das Mitleid vorraussetzt, dass es mir besser geht als dem Anderen. Mitgefühl dagegen kann ich empfinden, wenn ich auf einer Ebene mit dem Anderen stehe.

Ob Mitleid eine *negative Konnotation* hat, ist stark von der Situtation abhängig. Mit einem Tier Mitleid zu haben ist eine positive Eigenschaft, aber "man leidet mit dem Tier", fühlt sich also selbst schlecht.

Bei Mitmenschen ist es schwierig. Generell ist die Fähigkeit Mitleid zu empfinden etwas positives. Allerdings kann es das Gegenüber in seinem Selbstwertgefühl verletzten, als bemitleidenswerte Person gesehen zu werden. Das Gegenüber wird durch mein Mitleid sozusagen "zum Opfer gemacht". Je nach Charakter kann das leichte oder starke abwehrende Reaktionen hervorrufen.

> Im Unterricht ist die Frage, ob wir behinderten Menschen aus Mitleid oder aus Mitgefühl helfen, unbeantwortet geblieben...

Ob man behinderten Menschen aus Mitleid oder Mitgefühl hilft, ist wahrscheinlich von Person zu Person unterschiedlich. Es gibt bestimmt auch mehr Motive zur Hilfsbereitschaft als nur diese zwei.

Ich versuche bewusst nicht den Eindruck von Mitleid zu erwecken, wenn ich helfe, damit sich mein Gegenüber nicht unwohl fühlt.

Comment: vielen Dank!!! sehr hilfreich!

Answer (score 1):

> Hat das Wort Mitleid eine positive oder negative Konnotation im Deutschen?

Das hängt sehr vom Kontext und dem *Auge des Betrachters* ab.

In den meisten Fällen wollen Betroffene kein *Mitleid* sondern eher *Mitgefühl*, was ein gewisses Mass an Sensibilität voraussetzt.

Es sei denn wir sprechen von *Selbstmitleid*, welches generell eher als negativ konnotiert ist.

---

> Im Unterricht ist die Frage, ob wir behinderten Menschen aus Mitleid oder aus Mitgefühl helfen, unbeantwortet geblieben...

Wie aus den diversen Kommentaren zu dieser Antwort ersichtlich ist, steht m.E. erstmal das *Mitgefühl* im Vordergrund.

Ein echtes *Mitleid* kann eine nicht behinderte Person nicht wirklich empfinden, da sie nicht weiss wie sich die Behinderung im täglichen Leben auswirkt.

Für mich pesönlich ist der Respekt, und die Wahrung der Selbstbestimmtheit eines Gegenübers der wichtigste Aspekt.

Also erst fragen, und der Person den Raum geben, bestimmte Dinge selbst erledigen zu können.

*Mitleid* hat für mich so die Konnotation

> "Oh mei, der schafft das nicht. Ich helfe ihm mal eben."

*Mitgefühl* ist eben eher das Nachfragen, und eingehen auf die Person.

Comment: "In den meisten Fällen ..." - hast Du das gezählt? Angenommen derjenige, mit dem ein anderer Mitleid hat, leidet gar nicht - das wäre ja ein triftiger Grund Mitleid abzulehnen, aber ist es dann überhaupt Mitleid? Der, mit dem angeblichen mitgelitten wird, leidet ja dann gar nicht. Umgekehrt beim Selbstmitleid: Derjenige, der es selbst verspürt, bewertet der das negativ? Wenn man unterstellt, dass sich das meiste Selbstmitleid ohne weitere Zeugen abspielt, dann ist auch die Unterstellung der generellen Ablehnung vielleicht ein Irrtum, weil geheuchelt wird. Jeder tut so, als stünde er drüber.

Comment: … ich bin einem Mann im Rollstuhl in der U-Bahn zu Hilfe geeilt, worauf er mir ziemlich schroff sagte "ich schaffe es alleine, ich brauche Ihr Mitleid nicht!" Später habe ich mich gefragt, ob das Wort "Mitleid" im Deutschen negativ zu bewerten ist... und diese Frage hat mich hierher geführt

Comment: @userunknown Ich bin von _Mitleid_ ggü. benachteiligten Personengruppen ausgegangen. Ich habe es freilich nicht gezählt, aber nach meiner Erfahrung verlangen z.B. körperlich oder geistig Behinderte eher nach Respekt und _Mitgefühl_, denn _Mitleid_.

Comment: @Serena Diese Reaktion ist als relativ normal zu bewerten. Am besten ist es in solchen Fällen einfach zu Fragen _"Kann ich Ihnen irgendwie helfen?" /  "Benötigen sie vielleicht Hilfe?"_. Ich weiss nicht genau was Du mit _"Zu Hilfe geeilt"_ wirklich gemacht hast. Aber z.B. einfach die Kontrolle über den Rollstuhl der betreffenden Person zu übernehmen, ist sicherlich unangemessen und solch eine schroffe Antwort  ist durchaus erwartbar. Respekt, Mitgefühl und Sensibilität ist angesagt.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ: ich wollte ihm helfen, die Tür aufzumachen, weil er selbst mit der Hand irgendwie nicht hinkommen konnte... und ich war etwas verblüfft, weil ich es definitiv nicht aus "pity" gemacht habe

Comment: @Serena Andererseits gibt es auch behinderte Menschen, die ob Ihres Schicksals auch einfach nur verbittert und verschlossen sind, daher hatte ich das _Selbstmitleid_ erwähnt.

Comment: @Serena _"ich wollte ihm helfen, die Tür aufzumachen"_ "Darf ich Ihnen helfen die Tür zu öffnen?" Respektvolle Frage. "Nein Danke, ich schaff das schon alleine."  Respektvolle Antwort. So einfach ist das. Aber da gehören natürlich zwei dazu ;-).

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ: besten Dank! für die Zukunft weiß ich Bescheid =)

Comment: @Serena Ich habe auch meine Antwort noch mal ein bisschen aktualisiert. Ich bezeichne mich selbst übrigens als Buddhist und _Mitgefühl_ hat da eine ganz besondere, zentrale Bedeutung. _Mitleid_ ist eher schlecht übersetzt aus den Schriften und Lehren.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Mitleid empfinden auch Eltern, wenn sich ihre kleinen Kinder irgendwo stoßen. Wenn die Katze klagend vor der Tür steht und raus will, aber nicht raus darf. Mit dem Zebra im Naturfilm, das vom Löwen gerissen wird, dem Filmheld der von der Schönheit verschmäht wird, Armen, Verunfallten, Kriegs- und Naturkatastrophenopfern die uns in den Nachrichten begegnen. Kranken Angehörigen und Freunden, denen das Rad gestohlen wurde - Mitleid ist so prävalent, dass es nicht plausibel erscheint, dass es meist deplaziert sein soll. Das heißt nicht, dass es immer angemessen ist oder geäußert wird.